# Neural Network doesn't work with large datasets

Tags: java, machine-learning, neural-network, mnist

I developed a simple ANN in Java which uses backpropagation and mini_batch stochastic gradient descent.
With simple problems such as XOR or small datasets such as the [Iris dataset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set) it works perfectly.

```
FileReader file = new FileReader("iris1.txt");
Scanner s = new Scanner(file).useLocale(Locale.US);
double[][] x = new double[4][147];
double[][] y = new double[3][147];
for(int i=0; i<x[0].length; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<x.length; j++){
        x[j][i] = s.nextDouble();
    }
}
for(int i=0; i<y[0].length; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<y.length; j++){
        y[j][i] = s.nextDouble();
    }
}

double[][] test = {{5.0, 5.7, 5.9, 4.9},{3.3, 2.8, 3.0, 3.1},{1.4, 4.1, 5.1, 1.6},{0.2, 1.3, 1.8, 0.4}};
double[][] lbl = {{1, 0, 0, 1},{0, 1, 0, 0},{0, 0, 1, 0}};
NeuralNetwork2 NN = new NeuralNetwork2(x, y, 30, test, lbl);

NN.train(0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 100, 3); // rate, momentum, decay, epochs, batch size
double[][] result = NN.a_3(test);

for(int i=0; i<result.length; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<result[0].length; j++){
        System.out.print((float)result[i][j]+ " | ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Gives the rigth result:

```
Completed epoch 100 acc:1.0
0.9979585 | 0.002576745 | 6.41456E-5 | 0.9972225 | 
0.0017186871 | 0.99348587 | 0.047361016 | 0.0023599463 | 
2.234334E-6 | 0.0026515499 | 0.95999074 | 2.7198328E-6 |
```

But with more complex dataset, such as the [poker hand](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Poker+Hand) one or the [MNIST](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) digit recognition dataset, it outputs just random predictions.
I tried many learning rates and batch sizes without seeing any improvement.

```
double[][] x = MNIST_reader.ImgReader("train-images.idx3-ubyte",6000);
double[][] y = MNIST_reader.LblReader("train-labels.idx1-ubyte",6000);
double[][] test = MNIST_reader.ImgReader("train-images.idx3-ubyte",10);
double[][] labels = MNIST_reader.LblReader("train-labels.idx1-ubyte",10);

System.out.println("Starting training");

NeuralNetwork2 NN = new NeuralNetwork2(x, y, 5);
NN.train(3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10, 10);
System.out.println("Done!");      

double[][] result = a_3(test);
for(int i=0; i<result.length; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<result[0].length; j++){
        System.out.print(result[i][j]+ " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This code outputs this strange result, with all the columns being the same

```
Completed epoch 10 acc:0.2
Done!
6.3996454E-4 6.3996454E-4 6.3996454E-4 6.3996454E-4 6.3996454E-4 6.3996454E-4 6.3996454E-4 6.3996454E-4 6.3996454E-4 6.3996454E-4 
0.067095816 0.067095816 0.067095816 0.067095816 0.067095816 0.067095816 0.067095816 0.067095816 0.067095816 0.067095816 
0.0038170302 0.0038170302 0.0038170302 0.0038170302 0.0038170302 0.0038170302 0.0038170302 0.0038170302 0.0038170302 0.0038170302 
0.016894313 0.016894313 0.016894313 0.016894313 0.016894313 0.016894313 0.016894313 0.016894313 0.016894313 0.016894313 
0.09347311 0.09347311 0.09347311 0.09347311 0.09347311 0.09347311 0.09347311 0.09347311 0.09347311 0.09347311 
0.013979352 0.013979352 0.013979352 0.013979352 0.013979352 0.013979352 0.013979352 0.013979352 0.013979352 0.013979352 
0.067910604 0.067910604 0.067910604 0.067910604 0.067910604 0.067910604 0.067910604 0.067910604 0.067910604 0.067910604 
0.030364795 0.030364795 0.030364795 0.030364795 0.030364795 0.030364795 0.030364795 0.030364795 0.030364795 0.030364795 
0.079609774 0.079609774 0.079609774 0.079609774 0.079609774 0.079609774 0.079609774 0.079609774 0.079609774 0.079609774 
0.0031235535 0.0031235535 0.0031235535 0.0031235535 0.0031235535 0.0031235535 0.0031235535 0.0031235535 0.0031235535 0.0031235535
```

Any idea about what's wrong here?

Comment: Did you try different learning rate: 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, ... ? Or did your training cost decrease over time at all?

Comment: I tried different learning rates